# Do the newest amd graphics drivers still crash Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, ati, graphics, fglrx

I've had a lot of trouble with fglrx drivers in the past, and I don't particularly feel like re-installing Ubuntu today, so does anyone know if the current amd software(seeing they've made an entirely different distribution for Ubuntu) will work on my system?

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. Graphics card: Radeon HD6750

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the latest FGLRX release from AMD ( AMD Catalyst™ 14.12 Proprietary Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64 12/8/2014), the system still hangs at least once per day using a R7-260, so I downgraded back to the open source driver. Your results may differ for the 6750.

You also mention re-installing Ubuntu, which shouldn't be necessary. If you can get a desktop, you can uninstall the drivers using Synaptic, or open a command shell and execute the AMd uninstall script. If the system wont boot in graphical mode, use the recovery mode and un-install the fglrx drivers via dpkg (if installed as a package) or the ATi uninstall script (which I think was in /usr/share/ATI).